# High Level Design Document for SSO Project

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, architecture, single-sign-on, identity

I am technical writer who is working on Single Sign-On Project that needs to be formulated in a High Level Design Document, but I find some difficulties in writing the document as it is my first time in SSO domain.

Would you kindly suggest the document's structure and other components that should be embedded in the HLD as the scope is:

- Using Identity Server 4 and .NET technology to build the SSO portal in order to enable end users to be authenticated and authorized to use the company 5 systems through API integration with those 5 systems.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You may find inspiration in the RFC - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.5. At the very least, you should stick to its terminology.